# Show angular ui tooltip after ng-model-debounce?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show an angular-ui tooltip after the ng-model-options debounce finishes. It should show on blur and hide on focus.

```
<input type="email"
 name="email" 
 ng-model="ctrl.email"
 ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"
 tooltip="Not valid"
 tooltip-trigger="blur"
 tooltip-enable="
 {[ 
   form.email.$invalid && 
   form.email.$dirty && 
   !form.email.$pending
 ]}">
```

I have no idea how to approach this apart form custom directive:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return ngModel.$viewValue;
}, function () {

   if (attrs.boTooltipToggle === 'true') {
       attrs.tooltipTrigger = 'blur';
   } else {
       attrs.tooltipTrigger = 'focus';
   }
});
```

The problem is that the tooltip is triggered (shown) immediately but my async validation start running after 500ms debounce time. I would like to trigger/show the tooltip after the async validation is complete. Do you have any ideas how to resolve this in a nice way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put an ID into the input.
2. Your watcher is not set to watch anything at the moment.

   `$scope.$watch("idValue", function () { // code ... });`